# SSIS: Debug SQLStatement in "Execute SQL" Task?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019

Our `SSIS` package has an *Execute SQL* Task that looks like below. As you can see it has parameters that are resolved in the `Parameter Mapping` tab. In this case, the four input parameters are `User::SalesId`, `User::SalesEmp`, `User::CustomMsg`, `User::SalesCountry`.

Question: how can I debug this call so that I know what SQL statement is being executed? Or at least know what the parameter values are at runtime.

I tried setting a breakpoint in `OnPreExecuteEvent` of the task, then I went to the Locals window. I was able to see the values of all the variables being used, which is fine. But I don't see the actual call of the stored procedure and its attached parameters.

Also, I can get the value of each individual using

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't love this answer but it's an option.

Print statement doesn't work from an Execute SQL Task. At least, I can't seem to find an option to listen for the event.

As you are currently not returning a resultset I'd make use of them. Since you are using OLE DB Connection manager, and that is an ordinal based token system with the `?` as the place holder, I am going to explicitly declare my variables and then populate them instead of the procedure call.

Fun note, I learned something today - do not declare your local variables as @p1, @p2 etc because the behind-the-scenes magic will also use those and you'll get duplicate declaration errors.

```
DECLARE @v0 int = ?
, @v1 int = ?
, @v2 int = ?
, @v3 int = ?;

SELECT @v0, @v1, @v2, @v3;

EXECUTE dbo.usp_RegisterSales @v0, @v1, @v2, @v3;
```

When that runs it will now generate a result set and we can just inspect the values afterwards.

General tab
[image]

Parameter tab

[image]

Result set tab
[image]

Putting it all together

[image]

The Script tasks simply emit any Read or Write variable's value to the output log via a RaiseInformation event

```
bool fireAgain = false;
string message = "{0}::{1} : {2}";
foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
{
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format(message, item.Namespace, item.Name, item.Value), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
}
```

The output is as shown

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SO_Trash\SO_Trash\Package7.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Pre, Scr Echo Back: User::EchoVariable->0
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Pre, Scr Echo Back: User::EchoVariable1->0
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Pre, Scr Echo Back: User::EchoVariable2->0
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Pre, Scr Echo Back: User::EchoVariable3->0
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Pre, Scr Echo Back: User::Variable->4
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Pre, Scr Echo Back: User::Variable1->3
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Pre, Scr Echo Back: User::Variable2->2
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Pre, Scr Echo Back: User::Variable3->1
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Post, Scr Echo Back: User::EchoVariable->4
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Post, Scr Echo Back: User::EchoVariable1->3
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Post, Scr Echo Back: User::EchoVariable2->2
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Post, Scr Echo Back: User::EchoVariable3->1
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Post, Scr Echo Back: User::Variable->4
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Post, Scr Echo Back: User::Variable1->3
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Post, Scr Echo Back: User::Variable2->2
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Back Post, Scr Echo Back: User::Variable3->1
SSIS package "C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SO_Trash\SO_Trash\Package7.dtsx" finished: Success.
```

If you have a longer term need for debugging/tracing/troubleshooting, I would create a table and stuff the aforementioned variables, one per row, + runtime metrics like @[System::StartTime] @[System::PackageName] @[System::ServerExecutionId] @[System::TaskID] and possibly @[System::MachineName]

Bam, now you have a reusable pattern that will keep track of parameter values across your packages for all time.